# What is a typical value for core-to-star efficiency?

Tags: star-formation, gas

I was reading [*Unfolding the Laws of Star Formation: The Density Distribution of Molecular Clouds*](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/344/6180/183.full.pdf) by Kainulainen et al., which discusses star formation rates and efficiencies.

One variable used is $\varepsilon_{\text{core}}$, the core-to-star efficiency, describing how much gas above the critical value of $s$, the logarithmic mean-normalized density, forms a star.

I'm using this parameter in some calculations, but I'd like to use an average value, as opposed to a value for a given molecular cloud.

What is a typical value for $\varepsilon_{\text{core}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this book](https://books.google.de/books?id=tQswBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA465&lpg=PA465&dq=core-to-star%20efficiency&source=bl&ots=JJOAAWFbxm&sig=dJQw-o9QGl8sH36DdeQe0kkRmkY&hl=it&sa=X&ei=gUNbVYumKISasAHk4IHwCg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=core-to-star%20efficiency&f=false) it seems you can have $\epsilon_{core}$ values raging from ~$30\%$ (a low value) up to $70\%$ (which is more "usual", i.e., requested by theories).

More information can be found [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/545/1/364/pdf/51522.web.pdf) and [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/761/2/156/pdf/apj_761_2_156.pdf).